# Proof verification for $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2-1} - \sqrt n) = +\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

> Show that:
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2-1} - \sqrt n\right) = +\infty
> $$

I've started it this way.

**Lemma**:

> Let $x_n$ and $y_n$ be two sequences. Claim:
>
> If:
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> &\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n =+\infty \\
> &\exists N\in \Bbb N, \ \forall n >N:y_n\ge c > 0
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Then:
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}(x_ny_n) = +\infty
> $$

**Proof**:

$\Box$ Start with definition of limit for this case:
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0,\ \exists N_1\in\Bbb N: \forall n > N_1 \implies x_n >\varepsilon
$$
Also:
$$
\exists N_2\in\Bbb N:\forall n>N_2 \implies y_n \ge c > 0
$$

Let:
$$
N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}
$$

Then starting from this $N$ we obtain:
$$
x_n\cdot y_n > c\cdot \varepsilon
$$

And we have that:
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0,\ \exists N =\max\{N_1, N_2\}\in\Bbb N: \forall n > N \implies x_n y_n > c\varepsilon
$$

Thus:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_ny_n) = +\infty \ \Box
$$

Now back to the initial problem. Let:
$$
z_n = \sqrt{n^2-1} - \sqrt n = \frac{n^2 - n - 1}{\sqrt{n^2 - 1} + \sqrt{n}}
$$

Define:
$$
x_n = n - 1 - {1\over n} \\
y_n = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2 - 1} + \sqrt{n}}
$$

Obviously $y_n \ge c > 0$ for some $N$ and $n>N$. Also $x_n \to +\infty$, then by lemma:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}{x_ny_n} = +\infty
$$

I know this is a bit overkill, but i wanted to use that exact lemma for the proof. Apart from that, is it valid?

BTW here is a [visualization](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0mb1o9yjnp) for $x_n, y_n$

**Update**

Since it is not clear where the lemma comes from here is the problem from the problem book right before the limit.

> Let:
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = a\ , \text{where}\ a = +\infty \ \text{or} \ a = -\infty
> $$
> Prove that if for all $n$ starting from some $N$ $y_n \ge c > 0$ then
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}x_ny_n = a
> $$
> And if for all $n$ starting from some $N$ $y_n \le c < 0$ then
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}x_ny_n = -a
> $$

No other constraints are given.

Comment: What's $c$ in your lemma? It feels like it's just randomly introduced?

Comment: @Jam, the exercise to prove this lemma comes right before the exercise on the limit (which in in the question section). No constraints for $c$ are given except for the fact that from some $N$ $y_n \ge c > 0$. This lemma is actually one of the several of the same kind in the exercise before limit.

Comment: I may be mistaken but I think you need more constraints on $c$. It seems like there's nothing stopping us from having $c=1/\varepsilon>0$, in which case $x_ny_n>c\varepsilon=1$ doesn't tell us much.

Comment: In other words, you've shown that $x$ is unbounded above and $y$ is bounded from below but how do we know that all $y$ have the same lower bound? And how do we know that the lower bound of $y$ doesn't get small very quickly (counteracting the size of $\varepsilon$)?

Comment: @Jam, I have updated the question and added more context of where that lemma came from

Comment: Your proof looks fine! For the sake of completeness, I would add a comment on how (towards the end) you obtain the bound for $y_n$ (which is indeed pretty easy).

Comment: @Jam Maybe that part has been edited since, but I don't see a problem with his constant $c$. This constant is independent of the choice for $\epsilon$

Answer (score 2):

All you need here is:

1. $\sqrt{n^2-1}\ge n-1$ if $n\ge 1$ (to see this, just square both sides);
2. $\sqrt n\le n/2$ if $n\ge 4$ (to see this, just square both sides).

So $\sqrt{n^2-1}-\sqrt n \ge n/2-1$ if $n\ge 4$.

And $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n/2-1) = +\infty$.